# Adding content of products based on subtype

Tags: entities

I have type (eg. women in clothes) and sub type (eg. jeans in women category). Now i need to add product but the product properties are decided by type(women) and sub type(jeans) and product is itself custom content type. I know in eCommerce website, this is basic situation but my project(**drupal 7**) is not eCommerce. I need to create this manually.

I have created the category and sub category as custom content type and mapped subcategory to category using entity reference. Now i have created new content type "product feature" and mapped to subcategory using entity reference. Now i need to add those product feature as field to the product when admin add the product. I need help in that.

Comment: Please be aware that we do not provide tutorials or step-by-step instructions for achieving functionality from a description, screenshot or other website, as explained in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead edit the question to include your attempt(s) to achieve the desired functionality and be as complete as possible. What have you tried, what did you expect, what actually happened? If you have any code to include in the question, please add it. The more complete you are, the better we can formulate an answer.

Comment: I have edit the question and specified where i am stuck and need help. I put that in broad way because i might have done wrong from start.

Comment: I do not understand why you linked categories with entity references. You can use taxonomy tags and created a parent-child structure with the arrows. (See [this](https://www.silverstripe.org/assets/1_7.jpg) for an example.) That is the 'normal' way of mapping categories. On the product you can then add a reference to the taxonomy term and it should show up on the edit form.

Comment: I did that so if admin select women category, the select list of sub category need be repopulate according to selected category. also i need to list category and sub category separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start by saying that content types are not meant to be used for grouping. Drupal content (nodes) come with permission checking and invoke a lot of hooks upon loading. That is not bad per sé (and in fact required for most content), but is overkill for grouping. Your parent child structure would involve 3 node loads where you want to display one.

If you need grouping, you need taxonomy. This offers almost the same functionality as content types with regards to fields and url aliases, but is much lighter in use. To start you could recreate your reference structure using taxonomy terms.

However, as I already explained in the comments, why not use nested taxonomy? You could place all your categories in one taxonomy vocabulary, allowing you to see, edit and rearrange all terms from one page. It would make your system much more maintainable. Also the fact that you state that you need second level terms to show up after selecting the first is possible. Have a look at [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select), [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) and [Client-side hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs). These offer exact that functionality.

Your last requirement (if there is more please edit them into the question):

> I need to list category and sub category separately

Depending on how you want to achieve this, is can be done. With views it is very easy. Add a filter to the view, select the parent term, then select that it should be empty. It should give you a list of top level taxonomy terms.

Comment: Category has content(banner image, header text and footer  text). so i created the content type. sub category also has content.

Comment: Taxonomy terms can have fields as well.

Comment: OK. I will try and let you know.

Comment: OK, i did the same using taxonomy. Now i need to create links for category and on link, i need to show list of subcategory. The page will be created using panels and views. Can taxonomy have links with url alias ?

Comment: Yes, taxonomy terms can have an url alias.